# Git pre commit and pre push hook for sonar runner

Tags: git, hook, gitlab, sonar-runner

Currently we have configure pre commit hook for sonar runner for subversion. Now our project is moving to Git (Gitlab) so we need to move our pre commit hook to Git pre commit and pre push hook.

We have two requirements

1. For every commit/push it should run sonar (using locally installed
   sonar runner) for static code analysis and find any violations then
   it should reject commit/push.
2. For every commit/push there should be valid jira id and it is
   assigned to person who is pushing code to git. Jira id should be
   part of commit message.

Do anybody have already implemented hook ?

Comment: @jthill I am not finding tool here. I am looking for solution.

Comment: @SilentWarrior did you find a solution for you problem? Would you like to share it with the community? I would be interested!

Answer (score 0):

I am still searching hook for sonar. But I can give you the JIRA number check hook. This hook only check if the JIRA number is valid from the JIRA server.

The JIRA number check hook client side `commig-msg` :

```
#!/bin/bash

JIRA_API_ISSUE_URL=http://jira7.{xxxxx}.org/rest/api/latest/issue/
HARD_MODE="false"
TIME_OUT=3

$(grep -i 'merge' "$1")
result=$?
if [ $result -eq 0 ];then
    # echo "INFO : can commit because 'merge' keyword exists."
    exit 0
fi

jira_num=$(grep -ohE -m 1 '[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0-9]+-[0-9]+' "$1" | head -1)
if [ "${jira_num}" == "" ];then
    echo "ERROR : commit does not contains JIRA_NUM. for example: PROJ-123"
    exit 1
fi
check_url=${JIRA_API_ISSUE_URL}${jira_num}
http_response=$(curl -m ${TIME_OUT} --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null ${check_url})

if [ ${HARD_MODE} == "true" ];then
    if [ "$http_response" -eq "401" ]; then
        # echo "INFO : can find jira issue number, allow commit";
        exit 0;
    else
        echo "ERROR : can not find the jira issue num:${jira_num}, please check: ${check_url}";
        exit 1;
    fi
else
    if [ "$http_response" -eq "404" ]; then
        echo "ERROR : can not find the jira issue num:${jira_num}, please check: ${check_url}";
        exit 2;
    elif [ "$http_response" -eq "000" ]; then
        echo "WARN : request time out or error occured, url:${check_url}, but allow commit in loose mode.";
        exit 0;
    else
        # echo "INFO : http response:${http_response}, not 404, allow commit. url: ${check_url}";
        exit 0;
    fi
fi
```

server side `update`:

```
#!/bin/bash

JIRA_API_ISSUE_URL=http://jira7.{xxxxx}.org/rest/api/latest/issue/
TIME_OUT=5

# --- Command line
refname="$1"
oldrev="$2"
newrev="$3"

# --- Safety check
# if [ -z "$GIT_DIR" ]; then
#    echo "Don't run this script from the command line." >&2
#    echo " (if you want, you could supply GIT_DIR then run" >&2
#    echo "  $0 <ref> <oldrev> <newrev>)" >&2
#    exit 1
# fi

if [ -z "$refname" -o -z "$oldrev" -o -z "$newrev" ]; then
    echo "usage: $0 <ref> <oldrev> <newrev>" >&2
    exit 1
fi

hashStrs=""
if [[ "$oldrev" =~ ^0+$ ]]; then
    # list everything reachable from newrev but not any heads
    hashStrs=$(git rev-list $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/* | sed 's/^/\^/') "$newrev")
else
    hashStrs=$(git rev-list "$oldrev..$newrev")
fi

# echo ${hashStrs}

hashArr=($hashStrs)
for hash in "${hashArr[@]}"; do
    message=$(git cat-file commit ${hash} | sed '1,/^$/d')
    if grep -i 'merge'<<<"$message";then
            # echo "INFO : branch: ${refname}, hash: ${hash}, 'merge' keyword exists. continue check other commit.."
        continue
    fi

    jira_num=$(grep -ohE -m 1 '[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0-9]+-[0-9]+' <<< "$message" | head -1)

    if [ "${jira_num}" == "" ];then
        echo "ERROR :  branch: ${refname}, hash commit (${hash}) does not contains JIRA_NUM. for example: PROJ-123"
        exit 1
    fi
    check_url=${JIRA_API_ISSUE_URL}${jira_num}
    http_response=$(curl -m ${TIME_OUT} --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null ${check_url})

    if [ "$http_response" -eq "401" ]; then
        # echo "INFO :  branch: ${refname}, hash commit (${hash}) can find jira issue number, continue check other commit..";
        continue;
    else
        echo "ERROR :  branch: ${refname}, hash commit (${hash}) can not find the jira issue num:${jira_num}, http code return:"${http_response}", please     check: ${check_url}";
        exit 1;
    fi

done


# --- Finished
# echo "INFO : branch: ${refname}, all commits with JIRA numbers, allow commit."
exit 0
```

refer:
http://note.youdao.com/noteshare?id=6cfe6bd7da2f5c009ac04061e24c4991